# How to check if user input is a float number in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program which checks if the number user enters is a float, but it does not work. I tried to check with `scanf`, but that did not work either.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

        float num1;

        printf("enter number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num1);



        if (scanf("%lf")) {

                printf("Good \n");
        }
        else {
                printf("Bad \n");
        }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to "enter a float"? (Users don't actually enter floats; users enter sequences of characters)

Comment: scanf is quite dangerous.  It is a serious security risk in  C (buffer overflow, anyone) and really should be retired.    Use getline to get the number as a string and write a function to test and see if it is a valid floating-point number.

Comment: @ncmathsadist OP's use of `scanf()` will not overflow.  `getline()` is not standard C although source code readily available.  Agree `scanf()` source be retired.

Comment: never heard that scanf is dangerous

Answer (score 7):

Have you read any documentation on [`scanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)?

You need to check the return value like this

```
double value;
if (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1)
    printf("It's float: %f\n", value);
else
    printf("It's NOT float ... \n");
```

There is a way I prefer because it gives more control on subsequent input, `scanf()` is rarely really useful. Instead try `fgets()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];
    double value;
    char *endptr;
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
        return -1; /* Unexpected error */
    value = strtod(buffer, &endptr);
    if ((*endptr == '\0') || (isspace(*endptr) != 0))
        printf("It's float: %f\n", value);
    else
        printf("It's NOT float ...\n");
}
```

Comment: You might want to note how the return value indicates the number of successful assignments, and that a return value of `1` isn't always equivalent to success. My `$0.02`.

Comment: Need to check `if (*endptr == buffer)` else no conversion occurred.  `if (*endptr == '\0')` typically fails as `*endptr` --> `\n`.  2nd half needs work.

Comment: @Dogbert I am so tired of writing about it on SO that I left the link so the reader can find out.

Comment: I think there's a comma missing before stdin inside the fgets function.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to test if a string converts to a `double` is to use `strtod()`.

`strtod()` can be tricky to use.  With `strtod(char *s, char *endptr)`, if `s == endptr`, conversion failed.  Else check the string starting at `endptr` for offending characters.

Overflow/underflow issues are not addressed here other than to say `strtod()` and conversion to `float` will readily convert to zero or infinity - both which are typically representable as a `float`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool is_float(const char *s, float *dest) {
  if (s == NULL) {
    return false;
  }
  char *endptr;
  *dest = (float) strtod(s, &endptr);
  if (s == endptr) {
    return false; // no conversion;
  }
  // Look at trailing text
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *endptr))
    endptr++;
  return *endptr == '\0';
}

void is_float_test(const char *s) {
  float x;
  printf("Test(\"%s\"):\n", s ? s : "NULL");
  if (is_float(s, &x)) {
    printf("Good (float) %e\n", x);
  } else {
    puts("Bad (float)");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  // Test cases
  is_float_test("123");
  is_float_test(" 123");
  is_float_test("123.456\n");
  is_float_test("123  ");
  is_float_test("123e123");
  is_float_test("123e456");
  is_float_test("  123 xyz");
  is_float_test("  abc");
  is_float_test(" ");
  is_float_test("");

  // Chance for user input
  char buffer[80];
  is_float_test(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Test("123"):
Good (float) 1.230000e+02
Test(" 123"):
Good (float) 1.230000e+02
Test("123.456
"):
Good (float) 1.234560e+02
Test("123  "):
Good (float) 1.230000e+02
Test("123e123"):
Good (float) inf
Test("123e456"):
Good (float) inf
Test("  123 xyz"):
Bad (float)
Test("  abc"):
Bad (float)
Test(" "):
Bad (float)
Test(""):
Bad (float)
```