# How to check if an argument contains a character or the number 0 in C?

Tags: c, command-line

back here again with another little puzzle that I have seemed to have made for myself.

---

Essentially, I have a program that takes input from the command line, and performs a calculation on the numbers by using the operator within the command line. E.g. In command line, I'd have the values "3 + 5", the output of the program would be 8. My question is, how do I check if there is a character or the number 0 in one of the arguments? I've used  `argv[]` to find the floating numbers, my guess would be that it is somewhere along the line of using the same method? Any guidance would be great! Here's my code for analysis.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

float num1, num2, sum = 0;
char operator;

if (argc != 4){
    printf("invalid input");
} else if
    (argc == 4){
    sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &num1);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &operator);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%f", &num2);

    switch (operator){
        case '+':
            sum = num1 + num2;
            printf("%f",sum);
            break;
        case '-':
            sum = num1 - num2;
            printf("%f",sum);
            break;
        case '*':
            sum = num1 * num2;
            printf("%f",sum);
            break;
        case '/':
            sum = num1 / num2;
            printf("%f",sum);
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid input");
    }
  }
}
```

Just for time saving, the operator section functions as it should, I'm only trying to solve the issues with there being a 0 or char in arguments 1 and 3 on the command line.

Comment: side notes: `*` may need to be quoted or escaped as it may be handled specially by the shell.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your issue is.  Do you have a problem in the case that you pass `0` as one of the arguments?

Comment: See [How to check if user input is a float number in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33621681/971127)

Comment: @xing `"123@456"` might return `1`.

Comment: It isn't clear what kind of problem you are experiencing. Can you show input that causes your program to produce incorrect results? If you want to *check validity* of your input, note that `sscanf` returns a value. Find out how to use it. Better yet, use a different function like `strtod`. Also note that checking for 0 is trivial. I assume you want to avoid division by zero, so 0 is valid in all cases except as the rigth argument for `/`.

Comment: Apologies on confusion everyone. Input for the program in the command line output would be "number operator number" e.g. "8 / 2". I want to make sure that the sum does not allow 0 to be calculated (e.g. "5 / 0") and that characters are forbidden(e.g "4 + g"), displaying an error message if either a character or 0 is present.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't amend it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 - check the return value of `sscanf`.  The `*scanf` functions will return the number of successful conversions and assignments, or `EOF` if end-of-file or error are detected on a read.  If `argv[1]` or `argv[3]` start with non-numeric characters, then `sscanf` will return 0:

```
if ( sscanf( argv[1], "%f", &num1 ) != 1 )
{
  // input was not a valid float
}
```

At this point, you can make sure that `num1` is not 0-valued:

```
if ( num1 != 0.0 )
{
  // do something with num1
}
```

However...

That won't protect you if the user enters something like `12r` - `sscanf` will convert and assign the leading `12`, leaving `r` unread.  *In this specific case* that's not necessarily a fatal error, but ideally you'd like to detect and respond to bad input somehow, which brings us to...

Option 1a - in addition to checking the return value of `sscanf`, see if there are any trailing characters that are not converted:

```
#include <ctype.h> // for isspace
...
char dummy;
...
if ( sscanf( argv[1], "%f%c", &num1, &dummy ) == 2 )
{
  /**
   * If argv[1] is a valid floating point constant, then the only
   * thing dummy should contain is either a 0 or whitespace.
   */
  if ( !isspace( dummy ) && dummy != 0 )
  {
    // input was not a valid float
  }
  else
  {
    if ( num1 != 0.0 )
    {
      // do something with num1
    }
  }
}
```

To be honest, I don't like this approach much.  I prefer something like...

Option 2 - don't use `sscanf` at all; instead, use `strtod` to convert your inputs.  It gives us the same ability to catch bad input, but in a slightly less cumbersome way:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for strtod
#include <ctype.h>  // for isspace
...
char *dummy;

double tmp = strtod( argv[1], &dummy );
if ( !isspace( *dummy ) && *dummy != 0 ) )
{
  // input was not a valid float
}
else
{
  num1 = tmp;
}
```

In this case, `dummy` will point to the first character in `argv[1]` that isn't part of a valid floating-point value; again, if this character isn't whitespace or 0, your user entered an invalid input.

Be extra careful when using the `%c` conversion specifier in `*scanf` - it won't skip over any leading whitespace, so it could possibly pick up a newline or other whitespace unintentionally.  If you want to make sure you read the next *non*-whitespace character, put a blank space in front of it in the format string:

```
if ( sscanf( argv[2], " %c", &operator ) != 1 )
{
  // argv[2] only contained whitespace
}
```

Alternately, you can simply loop through `argv[2]` and look for the first non-whitespace character:

```
int i = 0; 
while ( argv[2][i] != 0 && isspace( argv[2][i] ) )
  i++;

if ( argv[2][i] == 0 )
{
  // argv[2] is empty or only contains whitespace
}
else
{
  operator = argv[2][i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will fail on a non-float input and if the input has trailing text such as `123@1234` as pointed out by BLUEPIXY.
Then test for zero by scanning for integers.

```
char extra[100] = "";
int result = 0;
int whole = 0;
int part = 0;

if ( 1 == ( sscanf(argv[1], "%f%99s", &num1, extra))) {//return of 0 or 2 is a problem
    result = sscanf ( argv[1], "%d.%d", &whole, &part);
    if ( result == 1 && whole == 0) {
        printf ( "zero\n");
        //do something
    }
    if ( result == 2 && whole == 0 && part == 0) {
        printf ( "zero\n");
        //do something
    }
}
else {
    printf ( "input not a float or contained trailing text\n");
    //do something
}
```