# isdigit like function that works on float

Tags: c, function

I am working on a simple temperature converter in C and I am facing an issue with the user input. I need a function like isdigit() that works on float. Any suggestion ???

Comment: What would such a function even do? Do you mean "is it an integer between 0 and 9 inclusive?"

Comment: Just implement it?

Comment: *user input* is, when you dig deep enough, just a sequence of characters, aka a string.

Comment: We need your code of what you have already done.

Comment: You can use the `strtof` or `strtod` functions to convert and validate an input string.

Comment: `isdigit` does not work on strings but characters. A floating point number *cannot fit in one character*, because the only valid values for one-character-long floating point would be exactly the digits 0-9 which would actually mean that it is an integer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in the C standard library.

You need to implement yourself this functionality.

Read more in [How to check if user input is a float number in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621681/how-to-check-if-user-input-is-a-float-number-in-c)

Comment: Thank you guys the comments. Actually, my program will deal float, it prompts the user to enter the temperature in Celcius, stores it in a float variable and the program then converts it in Fahrenheit and Kelvin. My issue is when user input is of char type or a string,  the program crashes.  Since isdigit() only works on int how do I validate float?

Comment: Check the link in my answer @user10321018.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to figure it out. Will implement as needed.