# How can I modify the c program such that if the user enters a non-float input,"invalid input" is shown to the user?

Tags: c, scanf

Here is the code:

```
// c program to add 10 elements entered by the user
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    float elements[10]; //declaring the array
    float sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i + 1); //getting the elements from  the user
        scanf("%f", &elements[i]);           //storing the elements
        sum += elements[i];                  //adding integers entered by the user to t   he sum variable
    }

    printf("sum of above entered elements is : %.4f", sum); //printing the sum to four decimal places
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you get a non-float (invalid input), you want to exit the program or just ask to input again?

Comment: Also, by `non-float` you mean `chars` or also an `int` value like `7` (that would be `7.0`).

Comment: You might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621700/2180316

Comment: thanks,i followed the link you mentioned in the comment and everything got sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

- Let the user input a string
- Validate input on the string
- Convert it to a float if everything is fine.